# Which kinds of queries is better for querying against conceptual model in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-sql

There are 3 way for querying against conceptual model in EF :

1. LINQ to Entity
2. Entity SQL
3. Query Builder Methods

Which one is better for which situation? Is there any performance issues for these 3 type of querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, all these ways are appropriate for production. 
In case you plan to reuse the LINQ to Entities query use CompiledQuery.
There is a number of performance peculiarities in Entity Framework - take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx).